# 100 or more internal javascript file optimizations?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization, cdn

I have web site and i have 100+ external javascript files, and it is loading very very slowly.
Generally the files are not so big they are probably 100-2500 byte.
Lode speed is connected from http requests (i think) ...

How can i optimize that ?

Comment: Concatenate and gzip them.

Comment: http://www.yottaa.com/blog/bid/259514/How-Does-Reducing-JavaScript-Requests-Minifying-JavaScript-Impact-Site-Performance

Comment: Do you need them every time, or are some of them used only in certain situations?

Comment: yes i need them every time ...

Comment: Wondering what you have in a 100-byte long JS file. If it's data you can output them as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers only support a certain number of HTTP channels, number [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768266/542251).

So with 100+ files all your HTTP requests are queuing and slowing down loading of the page.

So, it is (generally) much more efficient to download one large file than lots of small files. So your best optimisation for above is to put all your Js files into one (or a few) large(ish) files.

Answer (score 2):

A small PHP script and some clever URL rewriting designed to speed up the loading of pages that use many or large css and javascript files.

```
RewriteRule ^css/(.*\.css) /combine.php?type=css&files=$1
RewriteRule ^javascript/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

[full documentation](http://rakaz.nl/code/combine)